# What happened to "GTA: The Trilogy" on OSX?

Tags: macos, grand-theft-auto-series

I seem to be unable to dig up any official reviews on OSX port of GTA and besides of amazon.com in the USA it does not seem to be available in any other country.
I seem to be unable to find anybody who knows more about the "why" and the future of GTA for osx in general.

Is there some information about this?

Comment: Can't you buy it worldwide from http://gametreemac.com/search.php?mode=search&page=1?

Comment: i'll have look. but i would still be interested, what's going on: GTA is -- as far as i know -- a big title. why the total silence?

Answer (score 2):

These are (relatively) old games; this is not an official port by Rockstar but instead a port using (I believe) either Cedega or Cider, special porting products developed by TransGaming Inc. I've played a Cider port of San Andreas and it was good, but nothing special. I believe there's a lot of silence because a) Cider doesn't really have the graphical power to support RAGE and the new GTA games, b) this port is very late (San Andreas came out 6-7 years ago), c) most gamers using computers run Windows, and d) Rockstar is focused on their new products.